# Getting rid of duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Firstly sorry for the misleading title, wasn't really sure what to call it.

Below are a list of document id's - the different formatting is dependent on which department has completed it.  The same document however can be duplicated when the 2 departments both fill it out, as shown below with 07/32423 and ABC/32423/2007

```
DocumentID       Date Completed
07/11235             2007-02-01  
07/34234             2007-03-01
07/45433             2007-05-05
ABC/8678/2007        2007-07-14
ABC/3424/2007        2007-08-16
07/32423             2007-10-01
ABC/32423/2007       2007-10-01
```

I would like my query to bring back the following to eliminate these duplicates, so the required result would be

```
DocumentID       Date Completed
07/11235             2007-02-01  
07/34234             2007-03-01
07/45433             2007-05-05
ABC/8678/2007        2007-07-14
ABC/3424/2007        2007-08-16
07/32423             2007-10-01
```

Comment: How many formats are there? And what logic determinate if they are duplicates? Otherwise we cant help.

Comment: need more information. So the first part is a department> And a second part is a document id? And if more than one department filled it out, you want only the first one returned? What is your table structure?

Comment: Do you have a list of canonical document ids?